# How can i have access to my old account

Tags: facebook

How do I delete an extra account I created accidentally and have no idea what the password is?

A while back while trying to reactivate my account I inadvertently created a second account. I only became aware of this problem when my friends noticed I had two accounts.

I want to delete the unwanted account but I can't access it because I don't know the password that was used.

Comment: Try "Forgot your password?" on the login page.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the profile
2. Select Report/Block
3. Choose "This is my old account"
4. Select "I want to close this account"

You should get a message "The reported timeline will be deactivated after a review."